# Doctrine sort by 2 different entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine, relationship, forum

I'm building a forum with Symfony and I'm currently wondering on how I'm about to list the latest activity using Doctrine.

I have a OneToMany relationship between Topic & Post.

I'd have to check for the latest things happened, which might be a post on a topic, or a topic itself.

How would you guys do this as clean as possible?

I would probably UNION both somehow sort by date and select last 5.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you want to display exactly?
The forum summary with the category or list of topics in a category with the last post? Why the last 5?
I could give you a solution after answering these few questions. Thank you

Comment: Hello Florian! Well I'd like to show a list of Topics sorted by date. ( Newest first ), but when someone replies (Post) on a Topic that date should be used instead to sort on. If that makes any sense. I say only five because right now I'm building a widget for the frontpage. I will indeed need a full list on another page later, but that's just the LIMIT that changes I guess. Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT t.id, t.title, MAX(p.createdOn) as latestPost
 FROM forum_topic as t
    LEFT JOIN forum_post as p ON p.topic_id = t.id
    group by t.id
    order by latestPost DESC` would be something like this in MySQL, but would like a Doctrine solution :).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (It's a function of **repository post**) :

```
public function lastTopics(){
    // Build query
    $qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.topic', 't')
        ->addSelect('t')
        ->addGroupBy('p.id')
        ->addGroupBy('t.id')
        ->orderBy('p.dateCreation', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(5)
    ;

    // Get query
    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    // Return results
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Then just list the last 5 posts by viewing topics. Enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But would this not retreive the posts instead of the topics? Because when there is a new topic ( without any posts ), it won't show up now. But if the topic has a post, I would retrieve the last one and get information about who posted it etc.

Comment: The first topic will be displayed because there is always a message (that of the author of the topic).
If you just want select topic, remove addSelect('p') ;)

In the idea of ​​improvement, storing the date of the last message in the Topic entity optimizes the queries.

Comment: Thank you Florian, I will add the date of the last message right away as this is still in development. Thank you!